# How to open file with any exetension in Android?

Tags: android

I have an app in which user can upload file with any exetention(***.png***,***.mp3***,***.txt***,***.pdf***,***.bmp***,***.apk***,...etc)

In a nutshell-->** the file with any exe..!**

These files r displayed in list-view.

When user 'Tap' or 'click' on item from list-view intent will be called (`android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW`) and it should be open the respective application which installed in device.

**For Example**

If User Click on nature.png then intent will be called and suggest the applications like Gallery,PS Touch..etc(**As shown in screen shot1**)

If User Click on book.pdf then intent will be called and suggest the applications like MuPdf,Polaris Office,apv..etc(**As shown in screen shot2**)

**For .txt,.pdf,.png,.jpg**-- I have solved the problem by set mime type `intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mime);`

**and** also **for URL**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(https://www.google.co.in/));
```

It is working perfectly but for rest of the file extension i m still confused-
What to do? and how to do?

I have already dig around,but couldn't get satisfactorily answer..!

**My Questions:**

1. **How can i write code for any file extensions so that it will call respective applications that installed in device??**
2. **How to define custom file extensions in XML?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code will work for every file type:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), fileMimeType);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // no Activity to handle this kind of files
}
```

Of course, there should be an `Activity` in the system that knows how to handle the file of a certain type. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Egor-Thanks buddy for ur help...but if i upload .apk,.java,.xml or file without extension then??the answer given by u i have already implemented.!

Comment: @patelpratik if you put the file without extension ActivityNotFoundException will occur. You must enter the file extension to view the file. other wise you can't open the file

Answer (score 1):

Pointing to the first part of your question:

```
try
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
  startActivity(intent);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
  //tel the user to install viewer to perform this action
}
```

There's no need to specify the type. It will get it from the data URI.

Comment: @Dinesh-thanx buddy...but i m still confused..For mime-type the device will detect it by itself but for other file exe-how can it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void openFile() {
    try {
        File file = new File(G.DIR_APP + fileName);
        fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        fileIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/" + fileExtension);
        startActivity(fileIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(G.currentActivity, "Cant Find Your File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: This assumes good faith, and that the file will always be correctly named.

Comment: File extension doesn't always match what stays after `application/` in mime type. Even `application/` isn't guaranteed to be right for some file types.